# How to convert a sql stored procedure query into c# linq query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table that contains different date-wise submitted values, I have an enum field that has three types of values, Panding=0; Approved = 1, and denied= 2. Now I want to group by on ApplicantDate.This is my SQL query. But I can't to convert it LINQ. Please anyone help to convert the SQL query to LINQ?

**Date**         status
**1/1/2012    0

1/1/2012    1

2/1/2012    0

1/1/2012**    2

example: here bold date are like applicant date and status are the numbers

```
SELECT 
        Count(he.ApplicationDate) AS Total,
        MAX(he.ApplicationDate) AS ApplicationDate,
        SUM(CASE WHEN he.Status=0 then 1 else 0 end )AS Last12MonthTotalPending,
        SUM(CASE WHEN he.Status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS Last12MonthTotalApproved,
        SUM(CASE WHEN he.Status = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END )AS Last12MonthTotalDenied
    FROM dbo.Client_Heatings he
    WHERE he.ApplicationDate >= DATEADD(Year,-1,GETDATE()) AND he.ApplicationDate <= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY CAST(ApplicationDate AS DATE)
```

Comment: What you have tried and which part is problematic?

Comment: What is different from previous posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74105827/how-to-convert-this-sql-query-into-linq-query

Comment: @jdweng
 Yes, That is are different

Comment: @MizanurRahaman, start writing LINQ query and post which part you cannot write. SO is not free SQL to LINQ conversion service.  Query is simple and I do not see problems here.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv, I just can write the SQL query, I can't imagine what is the LINQ.

Comment: You have to learn. It is like SQL but with it's own rules. Start from `GroupBy` and `Sum`. `query.GroupBy(x => x.ApplicationDate.Date).Select(g => new { Total = g.Count(),  Last12MonthTotalPending = g.Sum(x => x.Status == 0 ? 1 : 0) ... })`

Comment: @
Svyatoslav Danyliv, Thank You. New I should solve this.